# mongodb sort aggregated data by datetime

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a date consist of name, ip, and datetime.
I have the following pipeline for pymongo, which fives me the 
aggregated result for each name and count ,sorted by count

```
pipeline = [{'$group': {'_id': '$name', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
            {'$sort': {'count': -1}},
            {'$limit': 20},
            {'$skip': offset}]
```

But I also need, sorted data by newest then aggregated.
I tried the following pipeline, but result seems wrong.

```
pipeline = [{'$sort': {'datetime': -1}},
            {'$group': {'_id': '$name', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
            {'$limit': 20},
            {'$skip': offset}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us some data?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
This seems to be the right result

```
    pipeline = [{'$group': {'_id': '$name', 'count': {'$sum': 1}, 'datetime': {'$last': '$datetime'}}},
            {'$sort': {'datetime': -1}},
            {'$limit': 20},
            {'$skip': offset}
            ]
```